# How does the Magento database structure connect review summaries to review details?

Tags: magento-1.7, review

How can I relate a product review title, detail & nickname to a review with a score of 100? Looking at the tables, I can find this information between:

- `review_detail`:

This has the information for the `review_id`, `title`, `detail`, & `nickname`.

However, it doesn't have information regarding the score of the review. I can find scores under the following table:

- `review_entity_summary`:

This has the values for the product ID (`entity_pk_value`) and the `rating_summary`

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to have a column for `review_id`.

How can I relate these two directly within the database structure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `review_entity_summary` table keeps the general scores of a product.
The ones you see in the list of products.

They are calculated and stored in this table when a review is approved (I think).

The link between the reviews and the scores are kept in the table `rating_option_vote`.
You have 4 important columns:

`entity_pk_value` (that's basically the product id)

`rating_id` (you can have multiple rating criteria)

`review_id` (this is what you are looking for)

`percent` (the review score).

The values from this table are displayed in the list of reviews for a product.

Comment: Grok'd! Exactly what I was looking for. Was trawling through only the `review_*` tables. Doh!

Comment: I have written a detailed on article on table structure for product reviews - https://blog.magepsycho.com/import-product-reviews-in-magento-via-sql/