# How can I change the product that was reviewed?

Tags: magento-1.9

The customer left a review but it is linked to a different product than the item they reviewed. How can I change it to link to the correct product? v1.9.1.0

Answer (score 0):

if you go to catalog > reviews and ratings > customer reviews > all reviews ,   you should be able to change the product reviewed.

Comment: No, the product can't be changed by this method. The review can but not the product. I'll have to do it in the database.

Comment: You can alter the product ID related to the review, but that will not update the product's average rating. These are saved separately and would both need to be adjusted.

Comment: The review_entity_summary table keeps the general scores of a product. The ones you see in the list of products.
They are calculated and stored in this table when a review is approved (I think).
The link between the reviews and the scores are kept in the table ratin_option_vote. You have 4 important columns entity_pk_value (that's basically the product id), rating_id (you can have multiple rating criteria) and review_id (this is what you are looking for) and percent (the review score).
the values from this table are displayed in the list of reviews for a product.

Comment: Above comment from here   https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/61977/how-does-the-magento-database-structure-connect-review-summaries-to-review-detai